# Bettercap output file is empty after capture

Tags: sniffing, bettercap

I am trying to do a sniffing attack and I want to save a .pcap file with the result of the analysis. I use this command:

```
bettercap --interface eth0 -X --proxy --sniffer-output /root/Escritorio/file.pcap
```

But when I open the file, it's empty.

Why it is this happening? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that your ethernet port isn't yielding anything? Try it with another interface e.g. `wlan0` to see if that yields anything.

A suggestion: I think you're using the legacy version of bettercap. There's a new version (https://www.bettercap.org/) that takes less space, is more reliable, and faster - according to the website. If you got bettercap by typing "apt-get", that's going to download the old version.

Answer (score 0):

With latest version of bettercap run the following to log to a file with `-no-colors` e.g.:

```
bettercap -no-colors -eval "events.stream off; set events.stream.output ~/bettercap-events.log; events.stream on"
```

Or one can just run the eval commands in the console if it's already running. According to [this issue post](https://github.com/bettercap/bettercap/issues/169#issuecomment-501081017) one needs to restart the [events.stream](https://www.bettercap.org/modules/core/events.stream/) to get logging to a file to work.